# ansible-doc command for filters & plugins

Tags: ansible

I would like to list & read documentation from the ansible-doc command for example about `ipaddr` or `flatten`.

Is it possible? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `ansible-doc`

> Displays information on modules installed in Ansible libraries. It displays a terse listing of plugins and their short descriptions, provides a printout of their DOCUMENTATION strings ...

from the module source.

Therefore for [filters to manipulate data](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html) like [`flatten`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-list-variables) or [`ipaddr`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters_ipaddr.html) there is no such command.

**Further Information**

- [DOCUMENTATION block](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_modules_documenting.html#documentation-block)